# is_admin function is not working for me in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Hello I am not sure why 
    is_admin

is not Working for me.
Here is my code.

```
if($featuredADS == "0" || $availableADS == "0" || empty($result) && $countPosts >= $postLimitperUser && $postLimitOn == 1 && !is_admin()){
//Some Code here
}else{
//Some Code here Which is always Work for admin
}
```

I want to ignore this check for admin user. If user is admin then i want to run code from (else).

Comment: I suggest to use current_user_can($perm) instead of is_admin
The codex explain how to use is_admin : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Comment: You need some proper parenthesis to group all the conditions you are testing, as you have a mix of ANDs and ORs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The is_admin() conditional tag only checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed. Try [current_user_can()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
$is_admin = current_user_can('manage_options');  // all user they have mange option will get 

if ($is_admin) {
    echo "admin"
}
else
{
    echo "not admin"
}
```